# 'swear' with 'that clauses' and 'infinitives'

Tags: grammar, infinitives, clauses

When the word **swear** means *promise strongly to do something* we can use either a noun clause or an infinitive after it:

> I swear I will not tell anyone.
>
> I swear to seek revenge.

What if we use phrases like **to God** or **By Almighty God**?
Can we still use the same structures?

> I swear to God to seek revenge.
>
> I swear by Almighty God to seek revenge.

Are these sentences grammatically correct?

Answer (score 2):

They're fine.

The first is a solemn oath TO God (assuming the Christian "God" - capital **G**).

The second is a solemn oath invoking Him as a witness (using the conventional male pronoun).

Your use of capitals was a bit hit and miss.

Comment: Thanks. That was a mistake. It's capital now. What about "I swear to you to seek revenge." is it possible to use things other than God?

Comment: You may swear to any divinity, angel, celebrity, etc that you choose. The supposition is that if you swear falsely to God, He will punish you accordingly. This theory awaits evidence. The thriving political class throws it into doubt.

Comment: My father used to say things like 'I swear to Almighty God I'll kill next door's dog if it pees on our path one more time!', but he never did do that.